# Invalid URI: The URI scheme is not valid when adding a service reference

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2015, wcf-data-services

To start with, I am a complete newbie when it comes to web services. 
What I eventually want to achieve is to create an Android/ios app with Xamarin that retrieves data from a remote MySQL database (send criteria and receive a list of names) and understand that web services is the way to go. I am working through the MS [Getting Started Tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733133(v=vs.110).aspx) with Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2015 and have got so far that the WCF service is running. I can enter the url in a browser and get the CalculatorService service page ok. My problem comes creating the WCF client. I add a new console application to my solution and add a reference to System.ServiceModel. I now have to add a service reference. So, as per instruction, I started the host service and entered
[See screen shot] in the Address bar and click the Go button. I then just get the error: 
Invalid URI: The URI scheme is not valid.

Can anyone please help me get a bit further?

Thanks,

Gerry

[This is the error(the first image I forgot to start the service)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gofmK.jpg)

Comment: Show us your client code, and how you are connecting to the service.

Comment: Hi Colin, 

I haven't got as far as adding code to the client. I have followed the steps for a Service Contract and Host. This is the third step in the tutorial "To create a Windows Communication Foundation client". I have added the reference System.ServiceModel and now need to add a reference to the Calculator Service. I first start up the GettingStartedHost console application by executing the .exe in the bin\debug folder. In the "Add a service reference" dialog I enter the above address and hit the Go button. Then the error. I am missing something somewhere..
Thanks, Gerry.

Comment: Include a screenshot of the error. It sounds a pretty generic error as it is now, some imagery will add a bit more context to this.

Comment: Colin, I have edited my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is occurring because you're pasting an invalid URL into the Service Reference Address Bar.

The URL to enter is just

> http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/Service

Update the Address to just that, and click `Go` again.